# Lighthouse GraphQL Generate PHP Laravel given GraphQL Schema

Tags: php, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

Is there a way to auto generate PHP skeleton code (class & functions) given graphql schema with mutation/interface?

The docs only mentioned the mutation/interface creation using php artisan command. https://lighthouse-php.com/5.2/api-reference/commands.html#mutation

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, you want to autogenereate the PHP code, based on what you have written in your graphql schema?

Comment: @OliverNybroe yes, correct especially for the mutations.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not something that lighthouse has support for, you will have to make a feature request or PR for that :)